# Calculating the required depth of a plywood box beam

Tags: plywood

I need to make a temporary work platform to go between two steel joists 8ft apart where the platform would be around 12in wide. To be on the safe side the platform should be able to support 2 adults, so say 400lb. I was thinking of making a simple box beam from 12mm constructional ply as I have enough available. My question is how deep should the beam be to support the required load?

Comment: Since the box beam (or girder) you describe is basically a wooden box, you might be able to use the [Sagulator](http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator) I saw mentioned in another question. "Plywood, fir" is one of the material choices (near the very end of the drop-down list).

Comment: Why not use a couple 2x6 or 2x8 framing joists with a plywood deck?

Comment: Adding to @Ashlar - put the joists on edge, put the plywood on top and then you could easily make a wider platform than the 12" which is at best marginal in width.

Comment: Sagulator is not the solution - it is meant for solid beams, not hollow or box beams.  You could use it for checking the capacity of the joists, should you decide to go in that direction.

Comment: My gut says a pair of 2x4s (on edge) and ply well screwed to both sides.

Comment: @AstPace One should be able to use the sagulator by adding the standing plywood pieces togetther. (given they are square to the load)

Comment: Remember to factor in dynamic load, two burly men = 400lb, but add in movement and you could get spikes that *greatly* exceed that weight. Whatever you end up going with I would err on the side of caution and over-engineer the hell out of it, you won't regret making it too strong. I would personally go with a couple of 2x6s, edge up, screwed and glued to the plywood. If you want to go with plywood only in the solution I'd make up substantial glue-ups of the plywood (basically DIY gluelam) that would stand in place of the 2x6s.

Comment: @losmano In Sagulator, the plywood is assumed to lie flat, not on edge. Much different bending characteristics in the two conditions.  Sagulator would be appropriate in the DIY gluelam that Graphus describes. Note that the layers of plywood must be glued to yield meaningful results.  Also, realize that Sagulator is not a predictor of when catastrophic failure occurs, but it is an indicator of when enough sag occurs that it is unsightly or too bouncy.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, sounds like 4" depth is the minimum, 6" is probably better, with 2-3 layers for the side walls. The problem is that the whole thing has to fit through a 3-floor high spiral staircase that's less than 3' wide so it will probably have to be taken up in pieces and assembled in the top room, which is why keeping it narrow is important. 18" wide might be doable, but I suspect any wider wouldn't fit through the staircase.

Comment: My FIL made some walk-boards for scaffolding many years ago. He made a 2x4 frame and laid a piece of plywood (or OSB) on top. They were probably 30-36" wide (from memory), and had 2 dowels running across the short dimension as handles. There was probably a 2x4 across the center of the long dimension to stiffen the OSB. I don't recall what he used to hook them over the horizonals of the scaffolding. These were plenty strong, and I don't ever recall feeling bouncy or concerned with two people working from one platform.

Comment: @FreeMan I wonder how much you could get away with the same construction with present-day materials. 2x4s ain't what they used to be, that's for sure. I went through a display of 2x wood recently and on some the growth rings were reasonably tight, on others they were literally the width of my forefinger!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a sagulator calculation. It is intended for box beams.

**Weight load as follows:**
8ft span : 12in width : 2x4 Douglas Fir : 40lb psf live load : 20lb psf dead load

Range (dependent of weight distribution) 
Maximum moment, Mmax: 427-480 (ft:lb)
Maximum shear force, Vmax: 120-240 (lb)
Nailing pattern: 5in on center

If doubling plywood, glue and nailing should be spaced no closer than 2in from lower layer.

**EDIT - HOW I CAME UP WITH VALUES:**
I was a General B Contractor and  I have an app that calculates the formula   based on materials(plywood and 2x?) used, what type of live and dead loads required, span length, width and returns the strength values of Mmax and Vmax based on various 2x? and nailing patterns. I based it on his 12mm plywood, 2x? douglas fir, with a live load of 40lb psf and 20lb psf dead load. The range is based on weight distribution whether evenly distributed or in one spot.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you came up with these numbers.

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "if doubling plywood" part means, can you expand? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanBurlison. If you want to use 2 layers of plywood on the walking surface. Make sure your nailing patter is still 5" on center but since the bottom layer has the same nailing pattern, make sure the top layer of plywoods nailing pattern is nailed in a way that the top layer nails are no closer than 2" to the nailing on the bottom layer of plywood. Or it will weaken the strength of the bottom layer of plywood.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks for the explanation :-)

Comment: A quick followup: I built three of these in total, 2 x 2"x4" 8' long joists (well, the metric equivalent) with 12 mm ply on either side, screwed about every 4". Completely rock-solid even with two adults on them - even the architects were happy to stand on them :-)

Comment: @AlanBurlison "even the architects were happy to stand on them :-)" Awesome, thanks for the follow up :D